# In feature selection, I came across a situation where NaN were filled by median of the column values

Tags: python, pandas, feature-selection

Why median value is used for NaN? Why not something else like mean? What is the logic behind using median value?

Comment: Median belongs to so called "robust" statistics. If a mean may be a subject to outliers, median is not so sensitive to them. This is the logic behind using median for imputation more often than mean

Comment: This is off-topic for Stack Overflow as it's about statistics/data analysis, not programming; [here is a question on stats.SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/257672/can-i-replace-nas-based-on-response-variable/) about the options for how to replace missing values in a dataset which may be useful. Please see the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) about what is on-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process you described is known as [imputation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imputation_(statistics)). Whether it makes sense to impute missing values with mean or median depends entirely on the dataset and the context of your problem.

Usually, it does not hurt to impute missing values with the mean. However, **if there are outliers in the dataset that adversely impact the mean, then it is probably a good idea to impute with the median**, as the median is a metric that is not influenced by the presence of outliers in the dataset.